# MAMP PRO MySQL Database Folder not found in MAMP/DB

Tags: mysql, mamp-pro

I have upgraded to MAMP Pro and mysql folders does not to appear in the location they were in MAMP/db

Which location MAMP Pro saves MySQL Databases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Updated version of MAMP Pro is saving the databases on a different location. I have installed the MAMP Pro for all users of the machine and can find one here

```
/Macintosh HD/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/
```

If the MAMP installation is for specific users, we can find it here

```
/Macintosh HD/Users/username/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/
```

Comment: If you've demoed MAMP Pro and started using it's database and want to transition over to plain old MAMP drag the Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ folder into the /Applications/MAMP/db/ folder and overwrite the mysql folder in it.

Comment: What about windows?